# Flask: How to pass newly created item from create route to view route?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=False)
    category = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=False)

    def __init__(self,title,content,category):
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.category = category

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Item %r>' % self.title
```

and a route to create them:

```
@app.route('/create',methods=('GET','POST'))
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('title') and request.form.get('content'):
            item = Item(request.form['title'],request.form['content'],request.form['category'])
            flash('Item created successfully','success')
            db.session.add(item)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('view'),itemid=item.id)
        else:
            flash('Title and Content are required.','danger')
    form = ItemForm()
    return render_template('create.html',form=form)
```

As you can see, if the user makes a post request,  and the content exists, it creates the item and redirects to the url for view with the parameter item.id as itemid. The view route:

```
@app.route('/view/<itemid>')
def view(itemid):
    item = Item.query.filter_by(itemid)
    return render_template('view.html',item=item)
```

Takes the itemid as a parameter in order to query for it, so its good that we are passing it with our redirect call! However, flask doesn't seem to get this part. It says:

BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'view'. Did you forget to specify values ['itemid']?

No I didn't forget to specify these values. In fact I even tried hardcoding them in. But it doesn't seem to find item.id as the itemid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Route parameters need to be specified inside `url_for`, not `redirect`. Check the placement of your `)`.

Comment: hooray! well done @univerio